# List of Categories for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm wanting to create a list of categories for a custom post type in Wordpress.

The custom post type is 'Books' and this has been set-up using the standard `taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),`

I'm not sure if there is a way to make `<?php wp_list_categories(); ?>` just show catgories from the post-type books.

I don't want to have to create a custom taxonomy as well.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you could change the name for your taxonomy you could use `<?php wp_list_categories( 'taxonomy' => 'custom_category_or_whateva', ); ?>`

If not read here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-categories-for-custom-post-type